# Are listeners removed on application close?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Let's say I have registrered following listener in `componentDidMount`:

```
    NetInfo.isConnected.addEventListener('connectionChange', this.props.connectionChange)
```

I need that listener to be active all the time when application is running.

In such case, is it necessary to call `removeEventListener` or it will be removed once the application is closed?

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the listener when the `componentWillUnmount` or when the state is `inactive`

```
componentDidMount() {
  AppState.addEventListener('change', this.handleAppStateChange);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
   //remove listener here
  AppState.removeEventListener('change', this.handleAppStateChange);
}

handleAppStateChange = (nextAppState) => {
  if (nextAppState === 'inactive') {
     //remove listener here
  }    
}
```

Hopefully this will resolve your issue

Comment: I am using wix navigation and unfortunately there is no root component. That means I would need to duplicate this logic in more than one component, hence my question. If it's not necessary to remove event listener because it will be removed on app close anyway then I don't need to implement this logic.

Comment: Generally, All you have to do is remove the listener in componentWillUnmount function and this will handle the issue

Comment: It won't, there is no root component to handle this inside componentWillUnmount - I would need to duplicate the logic

Comment: Where do you attach the event? It is the same place where you have to remove it

Comment: In wix navigation you can have one root at a time, and I need to start listeners once the application is launched.

Consider following flow:

Entry (root - start listeners, init app) -> Login (new root) -> Dashboard(new root)

In such case, when root is changed, componentWillUnmount is called and listeners from Entry will be removed. 

I would need to start/remove same listeners in Login and Dashboard. I hope that makes sense

Comment: @jmac did you ever come up with an answer for this? I'm wondering the same thing, mounting a listener outside of a component.